# Can't connect to Mysql - issue with my.cnf

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, configuration, amazon-ec2, config

I cannot seem to login properly to mysql on my amazon ec2 instance.

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

If I view `my.cnf` at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

it has the socket declaration as:

```
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

When, it is really looking for `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock` (based on the error)

My question is, how do I basically reset this value: `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock` to point to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  as currently setup in `my.cnf` ?

I've already verified, that `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` exists in this location

Thank you!

Comment: Is that the declaration for `[mysql]` or `[mysqld]`? One is for the server, the other for the client.

Comment: Well, socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is in both

Comment: The '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' is none existent in my.cnf

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to the same problem after restarting my EC2 server - I couldn't connect to mysql.
When I ran:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
```

it said that mysql was not running.

I had to do

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql
```

Comment: Works like charm even when you have .sock file in the same location as mentioned in my.cnf file. Thanks so much!

Comment: It work for me. First need to stop mysql service and then restart mysql.
Thanks @genegc

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer helps, I had the same problem on one of my servers at GC with Bitnami LampStack installed on Debian. Run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock /tmp
```

If you stop and start again MySQL service, you will need to run the command again.

Best regards,